# Deleting Temporary Files in ASP.NET MVC C# with TempFileCollection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a question concerning temporary files in ASP.NET 5 MVC C#.
I want to generate an ics file, then store it as a temporary file, send it with a mail and then delete the file.
Im trying this at my localhost. I'm starting the application, then do an API GET call (trough browser ....net/api/quotes) and in the GET method the sendMailWithIcal method is started. After I called the API, I stop the application in Visual Studio.

By searching through stackoverflow, i found the TempFileCollection. The problem is that i can't delete the file after i send the mail. I try it in two different ways, with: "System.IO.File.Delete(path)" or with "tempFiles.Delete()":

```
public void SendMailWithICal(string receiver, string subject, string textBody)
    {

        this._msg = new MailMessage(UserName, receiver);
        this._msg.Subject = subject;
        this._msg.Body = textBody;

        CalenderItems iCalender = new CalenderItems();
        iCalender.GenerateEvent("Neuer Kalendereintrag");

        var termin = iCalender.iCal;

        using (var tempFiles = new TempFileCollection())
        {
            tempFiles.AddFile("TempIcsFiles/file3.ics", false);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("TempIcsFiles/file3.ics", termin.ToString());

            Attachment atm = new Attachment("TempIcsFiles/file3.ics");
            this._msg.Attachments.Add(atm);

            System.IO.File.Delete(("TempIcsFiles/file3.ics"));   //Either i try this
            //tempFiles.Delete();                   //or this
          }
        this._smtpClient.Send(_msg);
    }
```

If I try it with System.IO.File.Delete, I receive an exception that it can't access the file, because it's used by another process. If I use  tempfiles.Delete(), there is no exception and it sends the mail, but the file is not deleted out of the folder TempIcsFiles inside the wwwroot Folder

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
I tried the solution Mikeal Nitell with this code:

```
var termin = iCalender.iCal;

        using (var tempFiles = new TempFileCollection())
        {
            tempFiles.AddFile("TempIcsFiles/file6.ics", false);

           //tempFiles.Delete();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText("TempIcsFiles/file6.ics", termin.ToString());

            Attachment atm = new Attachment("TempIcsFiles/file6.ics");

            this._msg.Attachments.Add(atm);
            this._smtpClient.Send(_msg);
            this._msg.Dispose();
            atm.Dispose();
        }
        System.IO.File.Delete(("TempIcsFiles/file6.ics"));
```

Now I receive the IOException that i cant access the file because another process is using it, already in the line with "System.IO.File.WriteAllText(...)"

If I uncomment this line, i receive a FileNotFoundException One line behind where i initialize the Attachment.

Answer (score 2):

You need to dispose your MailMessage. It keeps locks on the files you attach, and those locks aren't released until the message object is disposed. That is why you get an exception when you try to delete the file, and that is also why the TempFileCollection cannot delete it.

So, you need to put you MailMessage inside a using statement, or explicitly call Dispose on it before you dispose your TempfileCollection.